# Ensure HTML element is 300px from page bottom, without empty space

Tags: html, css

I have an `input` near the bottom of my page, as so:

[image]

This input has a dropdown (which is a `<div>` cotaining a `<ul>`) which appears dynamically i.e.

[image]

As this input is near the bottom of the page, when the dropdown appears, it requires the user to scroll down to see the entire dropdown, which I want to make not required, by making sure that the page end is at least 300px height away from the bottom of the `input`. I've tried doing this with `margin-bottom` - however this leaves 300px of whitespace before my pagination (obviously!) which I don't want.

What I really want to do is give it a margin-bottom at `z-index:1` layer, allowing other elements to sit in this margin space, but just making sure there is 300px before the page ends. Any suggestions?

(The input is `position:static`, so `bottom` can't be used, I don't think?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `margin-bottom: 300px` to your pagination, and make the dropdown pop over the pagination by setting the dropdown position to `position: absolute; top: 40px;` and its dimensions to something like `width: 100%; height: 300px`.

Don't forget to add `position: relative` to the parent element of your dropdown.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The margin-bottom on the pagination would need to be 300px minus the height of the pagination (including the space between the pagination and the bottom of the dropdown). Also, the dropdown should appear above the pagination anyway, without absolute positioning.

Comment: If both the pagination and the dropdown are staticly positioned, the dropdown will push down the pagination. Which may cause the browsers scrollbars to appear.

As to the 300px minus the height, you are absolutely right. Margin values may need to be tweaked afterwards.

Comment: An open dropdown field (`<select>`) is outside the flow of elements, it will not push other elements out of the way. See an example: http://jsfiddle.net/qMjMh/ Dropdowns have a lot of native behavior that is based on the browser.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the dropdown in question is a `<div>` element containing multiple other rows and not a `<select>` element.

Comment: The dropdown is a `<div>` containing a `<ul>` - apologies, I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @Chris Ah, that makes quite a bit of difference, then :P

Comment: I was avoiding this as I use my pagination elsewhere, but I guess I should just CSS properly and get over myself - it does provide exactly what I want! @robooneus, thanks for your contribution too, I've upvoted your answer as I can't accept both!

Comment: In my humble opinion letting the dropdown pop over the pagination looks better. However if you are burnt on positioning everything staticly, I suppose you could aswell put the input, dropdown and pagination into 1 single container and set the height of that container to 400px or something.

Comment: The dropdown over the pagination was my aim! However, just not off the bottom of the page. W/ regards to positioning everything statically, I'm using a library for this dropdown and many others across the site, which makes changing that difficult. In the end, I went with making the margin-bottom 200px only on focus, and using jQuery to scroll down to the bottom of the page at the same time...it's not elegant, but as what I actually wanted to do doesn't appear to be a thing in CSS, this does the job. Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the dropdown appear above the input field.

If that is clumsy, make the input a non-editable element and show a popup when the user clicks into it. Position the popup further up on the page.

If that's also clumsy, remember the scroll position, then create a 300px margin when the user starts to edit, scroll the page up. After editing, remove the margin and scroll down again.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I think I'll avoid the first couple as I have a number of these dropdowns, and want to keep activity consistent throughout them all. (Although I didn't mention that, apologies!) The last idea is promising, I'll have a play and see if it becomes too distracting or not! Thanks!